# is there any way i could minimize the Mysql database trip for this piece of code?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

i have a table called `propAmenities` which holds two column `amenity_id` and `property_id` basically the table holds the foreign keys.

now i have two insert data into this table, and while inserting data `property_id` column will have the same value for all rows that are to be inserted while `amentiy_id` value will vary, now for example the values may look like

```
INSERT INTO propAmenities(amenity_id, property_id) VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO propAmenities(amenity_id, property_id) VALUES(2,1);
INSERT INTO propAmenities(amenity_id, property_id) VALUES(3,1);
INSERT INTO propAmenities(amenity_id, property_id) VALUES(4,1);
INSERT INTO propAmenities(amenity_id, property_id) VALUES(5,1);
```

and the current code to insert the data i am using is:

```
public function savePropAmenities($amenityIds = array()) {
    if($this->validateRequired(array('propertyId'))) {
        foreach($amenityIds as $amenityId) {
            $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO
                                        propAmenities
                                        (amenity_id, property_id)
                                        VALUES
                                        (:amenityId, :propertyId)');
            $sth->bindParam(':amenityId', $amenityId);
            $sth->bindParam(':propertyId', $this->data['propertyId']);
            $sth->execute();    
        }
    }
}
```

the above code will run a loop and will make a frequent trip to database to insert the records. is there anyway i could cut of the trip and minimize it to one?

Comment: Why do you have a return in the for loop? That makes the above code only run once!

Comment: correctly pointed out i forgot about it, thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a multi value insert (for MySQL atleast)

```
INSERT INTO propAmenities (amenity_id, property_id) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)
```

Also you can set a default value for the field on the database.

```
ALTER propAmenities MODIFY COLUMN property_id INT DEFAULT 1;
```

Then you could do this

```
INSERT INTO propAmenities (amenity_id) VALUES (1), (2), (3)
```

Comment: the first statement of yours is what i was looking for, i wonder how i missed it :)

Comment: I found it by inspecting a mysqldump file at some point, I never noticed it myself until then either :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a reduce-to-one answer but heres how to make it more efficient:

Move

```
 $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO
                                        propAmenities
                                        (amenity_id, property_id)
                                        VALUES
                                        (:amenityId, :propertyId)');
$sth->bindParam(':propertyId', $this->data['propertyId']);
```

out of the for loop. There is no need to call it multiple times. This should reduce some traffic.

EDIT

so your code becomes

```
public function savePropAmenities($amenityIds = array()) {
    if($this->validateRequired(array('propertyId'))) {
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO
                                        propAmenities
                                        (amenity_id, property_id)
                                        VALUES
                                        (:amenityId, :propertyId)');
        $sth->bindParam(':propertyId', $this->data['propertyId']);
        foreach($amenityIds as $amenityId) {
            $sth->bindParam(':amenityId', $amenityId);

            $sth->execute();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am unable to understand what are you exactly trying to say, how come i will be able to insert amenity_id with your piece of code and that too without the loop?

Comment: don't remove the for loop, move them out of the for loop. see edit